# Calling WCF in SilverLight compoment

Tags: silverlight-3.0, wcf

The following code throws an exception which I have no idea what goes wrong , can anyone shed some light on this one please?

```
RestAPIDataContext ctx = GetContext();            
var songsQuery = (from item in ctx.Songs
                                  where item.Artist.Title == "George Michael"
                                  select item) as DataServiceQuery<SongsItem>;
                    songsQuery.BeginExecute(
                        (IAsyncResult asyncResult) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                                                                                 {
                                                                                     songsList.ItemsSource = songsQuery.EndExecute(asyncResult);
                                                                                 }), songsQuery
                        );
private static RestAPIDataContext GetContext()
        {
            RestAPIDataContext ctx =
              new RestAPIDataContext(
              new Uri("http://win-oirj50igics/restapi/_vti_bin/ListData.svc"));
            return ctx;
        }
```

System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while saving changes. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: 

  
  Request version '1.0' is too low for the response. The lowest supported version is '2.0'.

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryAsyncResult.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryAsyncResult.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at SLRest.MainPage.<>c_*DisplayClass3.<>c*_DisplayClass5.b__1()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the call stack it looks like you are using a ADO.Net data service framework. you can either try to update it using this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=4B710B89-8576-46CF-A4BF-331A9306D555&displaylang=en) or change the target framework of your caller application to 4.0.

Check this [link](http://www.silver-it.com/node/55) for details

Comment: Thanks mate , your solution work.But mine is not console app, it is SilverLight app.So I change my SilverLight app version from 3.0 to 4.0 and it works fine now.